# .htaccess rules to serve "bla.php?id=1" from static file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Situation**

I have files with names like

```
bla.php?id=1
```

(`bla.php` doesn't exist) that contain plain HTML code (which happens when you mirror a site with wget for example).

**Goal**

When accessing

```
domain.com/bla.php?id=1
```

it should serve from the static file `bla.php?id=1` instead of `bla.php` and appending the query string to it. Works with the question mark in hex, ie. `domain.com/bla.php%3Fid=1`, but then the URL would change and it shouldn't.

**Problem**

The solution I came up with is to rewrite question marks in the URL to hex internally via .htaccess, which so far I didn't get to work correctly. If anyone has a better idea to reach the goal of serving URLs containing query strings from static files, it would be very appreciated. Below is what I tried without luck:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /$1\%3F%{QUERY_STRING}? [NE,L]
```

Comment: @Jhon Wayne: is your goal is this: domain.com/bla.php%3Fid=1

Comment: Are you trying to do this: (domain.com/bla.php?id=1) to this (domain.com/bla.php%3Fid=1)

Comment: My goal is this `domain.com/bla.php?id=1` being served from a static HTML file named `bla.php?id=1`. To test this you can create a file with that name on any Apache server and then try to access it.

Comment: OK wait I just make for you in localhost, and I gonig to test

Comment: Please go to this link http://test.softbazz.com/index.php?id=1

Comment: Can you tell me, that will do with .htaccess?

Comment: you also can go to this link: http://test.softbazz.com/index.php?id=2

Comment: Ok so you have no `index.php` on this server, but a file named `index.php?id=1` which contains the "SUCCESS !" text, right? If so, it looks like you have the solution to my problem.

Comment: No I have index.php file in my server and I put in there some php codes

Comment: Are you want to rewrite the link or some thing else?

Comment: Then it's not really what I need, although doing this in PHP would be a solution as well, I want to work with static code only. Nevertheless it would be cool if you could provide the PHP code as an example in case no one has the solution I'm looking for, thanks for your help!

Comment: OK, I got that, wait. I just make some thing for you

Comment: Please go to this link: http://test.softbazz.com/John-Wayne

Comment: or go to here http://test.softbazz.com/Softbazz

Comment: The Actual file is this index.php?id=1 but link is this Softbazz, ok

Comment: Link **and** file name must be `index.php?id=1`, thats the goal here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
We have a solution for this, Please try the below code.

 RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
 RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1\%3F%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Finally someone was able to figure this out, thank you!

Comment: @John Wayne: But I just try in my host it is not working

Comment: @John Wayne: link is not coming?

Comment: It looks like you don't have a static file called `index.php?id=1` on your server then, the rules work perfectly fine for the issue I described above.